# Unable to identify which events a wx widget emits

Tags: wxpython

I have searched extensively but without success for a list showing the events which are emitted by each wx widget.  I have found a list of 271 events which are located in dir(wx), the names of only some of which suggest the widget they belong to.

Articles about a particular widget will often show *some* of the events emitted, but never a complete set.

Can anyone point me to the right place to find this information, or explain why I am looking for the wrong thing?

Comment: This might help https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/EventTypes_and_Event-Table_Macros

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [docs](https://docs.wxpython.org)? They show the events emitted by the widgets at the top of a page.